# Generate xml by only knowing the tag name and his indentation (explained when describing) - Java

Tags: java, xml

I have 2 Lists, which sizes are equal. The first list contains all xml tag names, that need to be generated, and the second one contains their indentation ( couldn't find a better word). Indentation is for example: The root element has indentation 0, his children have 1, and so on.

A better example:

```
XML TAGS  |  INDENT
root      |  0
child1    |  1
child12   |  2
child2    |  1
child22   |  2
```

XML Example:

```
<root>
  <child1>
    <child12></child12>
  </child1>
  <child2>
    <child22></child22>
  </child2>
</root>
```

My approach:

```
private static void generateXML() throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

    if (xmlNames.size() == indentationNumbers.size()) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.newDocument();

        // root element
        Element root = document.createElement(xmlNames.get(0));
        document.appendChild(root);
        int lastKnownIndentation = Integer.parseInt(indentationNumbers.get(0));

        loopThroughLists(document, lastKnownIndentation, root);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } else {
        // TODO Logger + Exception
    }
}


private static void loopThroughLists(Document document, int lastKnownIndentation, Element root) {

    for (int i = 1; i < xmlNames.size(); i++) {

        String xmlName = xmlNames.get(i);
        int indentaion = Integer.parseInt(indentationNumbers.get(i));
        Element element = null;

        if (xmlName.startsWith("@")) {
            continue;
        }

        if (indentaion == lastKnownIndentation + 1) {
            element = document.createElement(xmlName);
            root.appendChild(element);
        } else {
            loopThroughLists(document, indentaion, element);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use recursion to generate my xml based on indentation (as described before), but I'm always getting an StackOverflowError, which I know what it means, and I know I'm looping bad through the lists. Could you help me with a better approach ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You always start the loop at index 1 in your ``loopThroughLists`` function. The means you work with the tag name ``child1`` every single time.

Comment: I started at index 1 because I created my root element which is at index 0, before the `loopThroughLists`

Comment: I know and it's correct not to start it at 0. Buy each time you call your function recursively, you start at 1 again instead of starting at the next tag.

Comment: As pointed out by @f1sh, you are stuck at processing the node child1. The following code block is executed all the times..else {
            loopThroughLists(document, indentaion, element);
        }

Comment: So, to understand more. I need to pass the starting index to the function, so when the recursion call occurs, it should start at the index in previusly left, right ?

Comment: Also, you might have already noticed it, but your approach will need the node to be listed in the depth first manner.

Comment: Didn't quite catch that "in the depth first manner"

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a solution with a lexer- and parser generator.

I did something in this direction recently with [jflex](http://jflex.de/) and [CUP](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/).

Pros:

- Error detection
- You can extend the input and output
- It is a typical compiler problem (IMHO)

Cons:

- Learn compiler construction
- Learn using new tools
- Problem may be too small to make this solution feasible